# How to create an event when the animation ends?

Tags: jquery, html, animation, css

1 - How to create an event when the animation ends?
Animation written in css3

2 - How to Play the animation only when all data loaded in the browser ?
You can see

Many Thx.
[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/hfuGx/48/show/)

Comment: Why you don't use the javascript for css animations? Mean do animate using js/jquery. You can use jquery for css animations.

Comment: in css3 it is more faster motion and I think it take less Resources but if you have a good example I will glad to see Thx

Comment: Don't load jQuery plus a library just for this. Use native CSS3 animations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 -You need to add an animationEnd event listener

```
document.getElementById('animation-03').addEventListener('animationend', function () {
    alert('end')
}, false);
```

Make sure you add it for all browser vendors.

Here is a forked version: http://jsfiddle.net/Fj2vF/2/

2 - Do not worry about this. As the W3C specks say your animation will start only when everything is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Initiating and then handling css3 animations with Javascript/jQuery is quite easy.

Check example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/codepo8/ATS2S/8/)

You can use js library  [Move.js](http://visionmedia.github.com/move.js/) for it.