# IE 9 is not rendering the CSS transitions. What have I got wrong?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

Here are some, but definitely not all, of the resources I dug through trying to find syntax which will work in IE9:

http://files0.cnitblog.com/jv9/Migrating_Consumer_Preview_App_to_Release_Preview.pdf

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975245(v=vs.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff728624.aspx

[How to create an event when the animation ends?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11326699/how-to-create-an-event-when-the-animation-ends)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

... and this is the code after studying all that.

```
    function callback(Own33){
        return function(){
            var IdentifyMe;
            var beSure;
            var JustONEmindU;
            IdentifyMe=document.getElementById(LeftDA);
            IdentifyMe.addEventListener("mouseout", PerformReset, false);
            IdentifyMe.className = (window.transitionstart) ? "lessdark":"";
            JustONEmindU=document.getElementById(LeftDA);
            JustONEmindU.addEventListener("transitionend", function (evt) {
                var localone;
                localone = document.getElementById(LeftDA);
                localone.className = "LITel";
                localone.addEventListener("click", HeyClick3L, false);
            }, false);
        }
    }
```

and CSS :

```
    #LftTx1.lessdark{


 transition-duration:1s;
 transition-name: AnimOne;
 transition-timing-function: linear;
 transition-delay: 0s;
 transition-iteration-count: 1;
 transition-play-state: running;
 transition-direction: normal;

}
@keyframes AnimOne{
from{
top:3.9%;
width:11%;
height:25%;
opacity:0.6;
padding-top:0px;
padding-bottom:3.3%;
padding-left:1%;
border-top:1px solid red;
border-right:4px solid yellow;
border-bottom:1px solid red;
border-left:1px solid red;
border-top-left-radius:3px;
border-top-right-radius:3px;
border-bottom-left-radius:3px;
border-bottom-right-radius:3px;
text-align:left;
color:orange;
font-size: 0.7rem;
}
to  {
top:-18.7%;
width:15.7%;
height:25.3%;
padding-top:0.33%;
padding-bottom:4.7%;
padding-right:1.3%;
opacity:0.9;
border-top:2px solid #77702B;
border-right:2px solid #77702B;
border-bottom:2px solid #77702B;
border-left:2px solid #77702B;
border-top-left-radius:5px;
border-top-right-radius:5px;
border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
text-align:center;
color:#00B800;
font-size:1.1rem;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simply not working because neither CSS3 [**transitions**](http://caniuse.com/css-transitions) nor [**animations**](http://caniuse.com/css-animation) are supported by IE9 <

Comment: and here I thought 6 7 and 8 were the Baddies! the rot continued on into 9.  Tx.

Comment: IE 9 was released before these things were official standards, so it really should not support these things. For the record IE 11 is an awesome browser and supports standards just fine and has the best support for transitions and animations of any browser right now. If you don't work on Windows, please visit http://modern.ie to get free virtual machines and explore several other great tools and resources to help your development.